# what best practice security layer can be added on a public web service to restrict access to my android app only

Tags: android

I have a web service exposed publicly on internet. what (best mechansim) security layer can be added on this public web service to restrict access to my android app only.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a login mechanism for your app?

Comment: As of now there is no login mechanism but if providing logic mechanism is the only option then how can we achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is the only client that connects to your service, try HMAC:

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/